# msal angular - continuous reloading while authentication using MsalGuard on routing

Tags: angular, azure, oauth, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

I'm trying to implement `msal-v1` in my angular application to authenticate my enterprise application.

There are few routes in my application like below

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [MsalGuard] },
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [MsalGuard] },
  { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent, canActivate: [MsalGuard] }
];
```

and my MSAL config is like below

```
MsalModule.forRoot(
      {
        auth: {
          clientId: environment.clientId,
          authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/",
          validateAuthority: true,
          redirectUri: "https://example.com/",
          postLogoutRedirectUri:
            "https://example.com/",
          navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
        },
        cache: {
          cacheLocation: "localStorage",
          storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11
        },
        system: {
          logger: new Logger(loggerCallback, {
            level: LogLevel.Verbose,
            piiLoggingEnabled: true,
          }),
        }
      },
      {
        popUp: false,
        consentScopes: ["user.read", "openid", "profile"],
        unprotectedResources: ["https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/"],
        protectedResourceMap,
        extraQueryParameters: {},
      }
    )
```

The issue I'm facing here is, when I try to run the domain with `empty route`, then authentication is working fine and then redirecting to `home Component`/page. From then on, I was able to redirect to all pages with out any issues.

But when I'm trying to directly open `Profile/Search` routes, after the authorize call, the url is entering a `loop` by redirecting first to https://example.com/#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOi... and then to https://example.com/search#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOi... and then entering to https://example.com/#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOi... again and so on.

I have also observed a console issue saying `clientautherror: login_in_progress: error during login call - login is already in progress.`

can anyone let me know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try clearing your browser cache and cookies?

Comment: yes, have done that many times, but no luck

Comment: You can refer to similar issues [during login call - login is already in progress](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1549), [ClientAuthError: Login_In_Progress: Error during login call - login is already in progress.](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2234) and [Sometimes logins fail with login in progress](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1069)

Comment: If you have found the solution or workaround, you can post as an answer so that it will be helpful to those who might face the similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discussed the same issue in the github forum and have found a alternate solution by setting a new route without the `MsalGuard` but to the same `HomeComponent`.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [
      MsalGuard
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'auth-redirect',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    canActivate: [
      MsalGuard
    ]
  }
];
```

full details [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/4614)